# AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally drupal 7 on node submit

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

I have a site built in drupal 7 where I use an adding node form which uses ajax for form submission (I use the modal module or the ajax_entity module). In both case when I submit the code the node is not create and I receive the following error in a popup:

"An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information follows. Path: http://demo/q=modal/node/add/TestType/ajax/0" Status text:n/a ResponseText:Skip to main content"

I dont if this is important but the node form is divided in vertical tabs and it is opening in modal window. Also it includes textboxes,textareas and file upload field, but in this case still I havent used the file upload fields.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most of the type Drupal Ajax Http error occurs when Drupal cant find Base URL.
So to resolve this issue follow below steps

1. Set `$base_url` variable in settings.php
2. If you have written some custom module, then make sure that whenever you to execute Ajax, check base_url variable have proper value. You can verify base_url value by printing this variable.

Comment: thanks for the reply. my domain is of the form http://example.com/demo. In base_url I have it as $base_url = 'http://example.com/demo' but still no luck. Should I exclude the "/demo"? Also I red that I have to make some changes to htaccess file too so that to be the same with the base_url of settings.php but I cant figure out exactly how it has to be written.

Comment: No need to update htaccess file. Try to exclude `demo` from URL and also set `$cookie_domain` in `settings.php` . Also check apache error log and drupal dblog.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue and found that someone adjusted the X-Frame-Options in Apache. If you look in the browser's console log, I had this error displaying:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.example.com/file/ajax/field_heading_background_image/und/0/form-kfxURDN5ZPpN5pjFWajkPCDpMKJrrJthX9WVcY2K8' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

Adding this to your .htaccess should fix it, but you can also adjust the server configuration:

```
 Header always unset X-Frame-Options
 Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: Thank you Pete. I ll try that since I am stuck for long time now..Can I do that in plesk panel?

Comment: I think you need to do it in http.conf. If it's easier, just do it in .htaccess and see if it fixes the problem. Also, I edited my original comment to add another line to set it to SAMEORIGIN which should be a little bit more secure. Try the first line and test. If it works, include both.

Comment: I think this wasnt my problem...I did that and nothing happened..The only error I see now is Exception: Google API returned bad status.\nStatus: REQUEST_DENIED in geocoder_google() (line 69 of /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/geocoder/plugins/geocoder_handler/google.inc). I dont know if this is the reason but I need to search all the possibilities..

Comment: Have you got the Geocoder module installed with a working Google Maps API key? Your problem now sounds a lot different than the original question. Perhaps look here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2029889 or https://www.drupal.org/node/1234496

Comment: Actually,I supposed that this may cause the problem since I have an ajax form elsewhere (for comments) and it works perfectly..But on the other hand I created a different content type with no geofields and still I face the same problem...As concerns the errors in logs I dont see any other errors...thanks for the links!